# How to use Threads for Processing Many Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a C# requirement for individually processing a 'great many' (perhaps > 100,000) records. Running this process sequentially is proving to be very slow with each record taking a good second or so to complete (with a timeout error set at 5 seconds).

I would like to try running these tasks asynchronously by using a set number of worker 'threads' (I use the term 'thread' here cautiously as I am not sure if I should be looking at a thread, or a task or something else).

I have looked at the `ThreadPool`, but I can't imagine it could queue the volume of requests required.  My ideal pseudo code would look something like this...

```
public void ProcessRecords() {
    SetMaxNumberOfThreads(20);
    MyRecord rec;
    while ((rec = GetNextRecord()) != null) {
        var task = WaitForNextAvailableThreadFromPool(ProcessRecord(rec));
        task.Start()
    }
}
```

I will also need a mechanism that the processing method can report back to the parent/calling class.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with perhaps some example code?

Comment: Why do you want to report back?

Comment: I'd like to return a simple POCO class containing a couple of integers and a string.  This data will be used to update the UI whilst the process is running.

Comment: Is your processing IO bound or CPU bound?

Comment: You create this POCO for each record?

Comment: Where is the data coming from and what kind of processing are you doing with it? If it's coming from a database, the fastest option would be to do the processing on the database itself. Set-based operations with SQL are orders of magnitude faster that processing each record individually, even if you do it in parallel

Comment: Moreover, a ThreadPool doesn't queue tasks, it executes them. PLINQ is meant to handle larger data sizes than what you describe and runs on top of the ThreadPool. It does so by partitioning the data and using Tasks and pool threads to process them

Comment: The source records are coming from a text file (so are supplied quickly to the loop).  The ProcessRecord() method takes the string data from the loop and builds and inserts a database record after referencing a web service lookup.  The ProcessRecord() method needs to a return a status object to the calling application to keep the UI updated.

Comment: Take a look at what else is available in the TPL. This is about the easiest possible data-parallel situation there is.

Comment: How big is your *.txt file? Maybe it could be faster to read in the complete data first and then process it. You also should create one thread per cpu, because too many threads are decreasing your performance. Maybe it's possible to cache results from your webservice to reduce calls. You also should do bulk inserts and not row by row.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A possible simple solution would be to use a TPL Dataflow block which is a higher abstraction over the TPL with configurations for degree of parallelism and so forth. You simply create the block (`ActionBlock` in this case), `Post` everything to it, wait asynchronously for completion and TPL Dataflow handles all the rest for you:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<MyRecord>(
    rec => ProcessRecord(rec), 
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20});

MyRecord rec;
while ((rec = GetNextRecord()) != null)
{
     block.Post(rec);
}

block.Complete();
await block.Completion
```

Another benefit is that the block starts working as soon as the first record arrives and not only when all the records have been received.

If you need to report back on each record you can use a `TransformBlock` to do the actual processing and link an `ActionBlock` to it that does the updates:

```
var transform = new TransfromBlock<MyRecord, Report>(rec =>
{
    ProcessRecord(rec);
    return GenerateReport(rec);
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20});

var reporter = new ActionBlock<Report>(report =>
{
    RaiseEvent(report) // Or any other mechanism...
});

transform.LinkTo(reporter, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

MyRecord rec;
while ((rec = GetNextRecord()) != null)
{
     transform.Post(rec);
}

transform.Complete();
await transform.Completion
```

Comment: This works beautifully - thank you very much for taking the time to detail the approach - much appreciated.

Comment: @Neilski sure.. any time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using parallel processing with Actions?
ie, create a method to process a single record, add each record method as an action into a list, and then perform a parrallel.for on the list.

```
Dim list As New List(Of Action)
list.Add(New Action(Sub() MyMethod(myParameter)))
Parallel.ForEach(list, Sub(t) t.Invoke())
```

This is in vb.net, but I think you get the gist.